# Authentication of SOAP messages

Tags: spring-security, spring-ws

I have searched for a good example and cannopt find one.  I want to take the username and password from the SOAP header, and set the spring security context after I authenticate using our exisiting service methods.  I have implemented the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor and it validates the header element.  WHat I need to do in the callback, or some other mechanism, is create an uthetication context so I can access it later in our endpoint.

However, I dont think that the callback is the correct place to do it, as I keep getting password supplied no password errors.  I am new to spring security and integration.

Config:

```
     <bean id="SOAPSecurityInterceptor" class="com.ps.snt.ws.interceptor.SOAPSecurityInterceptor"> 
        <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken"/> 
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="callbackHandler"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="callbackHandler" class="com.ps.snt.ws.interceptor.SOAPSecurityValidationCallbackHandler">
   </bean>
```

callback:

```
public class SOAPSecurityValidationCallbackHandler extends  SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler {

     @Override
        protected void handleUsernameToken(WSPasswordCallback callback) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
            System.out.println("In security callback " + callback.getPassword());

            boolean valid = true;

            String token = callback.getIdentifier();
            String password = callback.getPassword();
            Integer zoneID = null;

            String username = null;


            StringBuffer errorMessages = new StringBuffer();

            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
                errorMessages.append("Username token cannot be empty");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\w]+\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(token);
                if(!matcher.matches()) {
                    valid = false;
                    errorMessages.append("Username token must be in the format 'user@zone'.");
                }
                else {
                    String[] parts = token.split("@");
                    username = parts[0];
                    zoneID = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                }

            }

            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                errorMessages.append("Password cannot be empty.");
                valid = false;
            }


            if(valid && username != null && zoneID != null) {
                LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
                LoginContextDO loginContextDO = loginService.getAuthenticatedLoginContext(username, password, zoneID);

                AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
                authentication.setDetails(loginContextDO);
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);


            } else {
                System.out.println("Authetnication failed!");
            }

        } 
}
```

My requirements are simple:
- validate the SOAP header (works)
- retrieve the username and password
- call our legacy service to create our login context
- set the spring security context (with logincontext as details) so I can use later in an endpoint

What mechanism can  I use to validate the soap header and set a security context from that header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpringSecurityPasswordValidationCallbackHandler` is for you. From Spring WS docs:

> The SpringSecurityPasswordValidationCallbackHandler validates plain text and digest passwords using a Spring Security UserDetailService to operate. It uses this service to retrieve the (digest of ) the password of the user specified in the token. The (digest of) the password contained in this details object is then compared with the digest in the message. If they are equal, the user has successfully authenticated, and a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is stored in theSecurityContextHolder. You can set the service using the userDetailsService. Additionally, you can set a userCache property, to cache loaded user details.

```
<beans>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SpringDigestPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.mycompany.app.dao.UserDetailService" />
    ...
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am still confused about how this will work.  The UserDetailsService class has a loadByUsername method, which returns a User object.  Can I assume that the authentication part has already been done before this class is called?

Comment: So I still need to implement a callback handler to get the password of the user.  From what I understand, I need to do the following: 1) Implement a callback handleUSernameToken method that retrieves the password from the database and sets it on the callback, 2) Spring authenticates the username by matching the SOAP message password with the one I set in the callback, 3) Implement the loadByUsername method to create a User object.  Where will I put my custom LoginContext object in this scheme, the User class doesn't seem to have any property I can use.

Comment: Not sure why you need it. If you follow with `WS-Security` everything should be there in the request...

Comment: I think I understnad now.  I was approaching the problem from the other side.  Basically, I create the user details service to load a user object, which is then authenticated against the SOAP header password.  I have one other issue though, my password from the database is encrypted, so how do I tell spring to encrypt the password in the SOAP message before comparing?  I cannot decrpyt passwords, but do have a utility method to encrypt a string.

Comment: See `UsernameTokenValidator` and `UsernameToken` should help to understand what's going on with passwords

Comment: Thanks.  I am opening a new question for the decryption problem.

Comment: I am need to get the plain text password and digest it before I used it to match against the digested password from DB. How I can do that? Above not working for me. Please share complete XML configuration files and configuration / implementation classes... Thanks